# Как записать бесконечный ряд

Tags: c++, математика, ряды, суммирование

необходимо вычислить бесконечный ряд с помощью циклов while и for, но никогда не имел с ним дел и не знаю как записать его на c++, нужна помощь. Отдельно буду благодарен за полное решение! )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где тут бесконечный ряд, если N конечно?

Comment: Извиняюсь, точно не знаю как называется это выражение

Comment: 2 вложенных цикла, в чём проблема-то? Если вы не понимаете этого, обратитесь к преподавателю, пусть объясняет. «Полное решение» только усугубит вашу ситуацию, препод должен знать, что у него не получилось донести информацию.

Comment: @shadow_warrior35 - Это сумма сумм, для каждого шага в первой сумме от -10 до 2 включительно вызывается вторая сумма от -3 до 15 включительно, т.е. у вас будет сумма 12 * 18 чисел

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Это так не работает. Если хотите разобраться, то расскажите нам, в чем именно сложность, покажите свои попытки, и т.п. А если хотите получить готовое решение - есть сайты, где это делают за денежку, без ехидных комментариев. :)

Comment: Достаточно найти человека, который объяснил бы эту математическую запись

Answer (score 5):

> Достаточно найти человека, который объяснил бы эту математическую запись

Хорошо, я попытаюсь... Этот изогнутый значок (буква "сигма") используется для сокращенной записи суммы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где [image: введите сюда описание изображения] - просто какое-то значение (член ряда), в общем случае зависящее от *n*. Оно может зависеть и еще от чего-то, например, некоторого второго значения *i*, и тогда ваша сумма сама становится каким-то [image: введите сюда описание изображения], которые - для разных *i* - тоже можно суммировать. Получается двойная (вложенная) сумма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так понятно?

Если у вас - подчеркиваю, **если** - задание дано без опечаток, то ваше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что внутренняя сумма суммирует нечто, *не зависящее* от индекса суммирования, т.е. просто надо умножить это значение на количество членов ряда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как *M*=15, вложенная сумма равна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и теперь нам нужно найти сумму арифметической прогрессии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, это вы учили в школе и сами сообразите, как посчитать эту сумму, которая равна -1976.

Это слишком просто, так что, вероятно, запись в начальной задаче

```
2i+j/3j
```

должна трактоваться как-то иначе. Например, (2i+j)/(3j) (невозможно - **деление на 0!**) или, как в программировании, (2i+j*j/3)... Это уж решайте сами.

Как написать это через циклы - вы сказали, что разберетесь сами.

P.S. Когда будете писать - не забывайте, чем целочисленное деление отличается от деления чисел с плавающей точкой...